# Send batch emails with different content Sendgrid

Tags: python, sdk, sendgrid

I wanna send emails to multiple users and each email is gonna has slightly different HTML content. I don't want to use dynamic templates because they don't support handlebars features I need.

Is there a way to send multiple emails with different content using Python SDK? I was trying to add personalization and subtitutions according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35040850/10675271 but without luck.